# new to android - why doe int variable > 1 java.lang.NullPointerException error?

Tags: java, android

here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < patharry.length; i++) { 

            String kik = patharry[i];
            int chckvalue = kik.length();

            if (chckvalue > 1){
```

it is this "if" statement which gives the java.lang.NullPointerException error... can you tell me why? and what would be a good work around ? I tried look through the java documentation but could not find anything.

here is the entire error:

```
10-16 15:52:09.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1521): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 15:52:09.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1521): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.customcalenderandroid/com.example.show_all.show_all}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-16 15:52:09.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-16 15:52:09.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-16 15:52:09.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-16 15:52:09.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-16 15:52:09.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-16 15:52:09.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-16 15:52:09.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-16 15:52:09.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 15:52:09.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-16 15:52:09.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-16 15:52:09.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-16 15:52:09.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-16 15:52:09.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1521): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-16 15:52:09.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at com.example.show_all.show_all.createData(show_all.java:82)
10-16 15:52:09.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at com.example.show_all.show_all.onCreate(show_all.java:40)
10-16 15:52:09.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-16 15:52:09.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-16 15:52:09.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-16 15:52:09.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you share the **complete** method/block ? I doubt this is the line that throws the NPE, possibly this `kik` buddy is `null`.

Comment: It is not possible for that line to throw null pointer.  Please show the entire method and the stack trace from logcat.

Comment: The last line of code you've posted will *not* produce a `NullPointerException`. The previous (non-whitespace) line will, if `kik` is null. We don't really have enough context here though, without more code, the data of `patharry`, and a stack trace...

Comment: Just wanted to add that I've found debugging android code via Eclipse to be imprecise, e.g. it sometimes appears to have stayed in a method despite hitting a `return` statement.

Comment: Try using the debugger in order to step through your code and see what is happening.  This should help you get started: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: What is at line 82 of `show_all.createData`? That is where your `NPE` is.

Comment: you are right - it is this line of code which gives the error:

Comment: int chckvalue = kk.length();

Comment: then `kik` is `null`. Debug and find out why.

Comment: Nope, that line can't throw it either.  Please listen to the advice, post the ENTIRE method and clearly mark line 82.

Comment: @codeMagic  If this is the actual code, then `kik` cannot be null since `patharray[i]` evaluates ok.  Nor can `patharray` be null since the for loop initialisation would except.  The OP is not telling the whole story.

Comment: @Simon why couldn't `patharry[i]` be `null` resulting in `kik` being `null`? `patharry` itself might not be `null` but it could be for index `i`

Comment: @codeMagic Because the for loop didn't throw an exception, then patharray cannot be null.  If it has no elements, then the for loop will exit without executing it's body since patharray.length will evaluate to 0.  It therefore has at least one element and therefore, patharray[i] cannot be null.  Ah, unless it's **elements** are null!

Comment: @Simon He's not saying `patharry == null`, he's saying that `patharry[i] == null`.

Comment: @Geobits Yeh, me being slow.  Time for caffeine ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be error is in this line: **int chckvalue = kik.length();** Because kik will be null. Debug your code and find where is that issue.
If you are not able to find then send code to me, I will check it.